# numpy custom function for sum of 1d/2d/3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a custom function that can return the sum of all elements in an array whether its 1d, 2d, or 3d. .

This is what I've come up with and it runs but the sums aren't correct and I can't figure out where its getting the numbers from.

```
array_1d = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array_2d = np.array([[1,3,4,5],[1,4,5,7]])
array_3d = np.array([[[1,3,4,5],[1,4,5,7]],[[6,7,8,9],[7,8,7,6]]])


def sum(array):

     sum = 0

     shape = np.shape(array)

     if len(np.shape(array)) == 3:
         for i in range(0,shape[2]):
             sum += array[0,1,2]
     elif len(np.shape(array)) == 2:
         for i in range(0,shape[1]):
             sum += array[0,1]
     elif len(np.shape(array)) == 1:
         for i in range(0,shape[0]):
             sum += array[0]
    
     return sum  


array_1d sum should be 15 but it gives me 5
array_2d sum should be 30 but i get 12
array_3d sum should be 88 but i get 20
```

what have i done wrong in my function?

(ps i know i can just use np.sum but its for an assignment)

Comment: You never use `i`.

Comment: You can use directly `np.sum` rather than user-defined function. For instance, `np.sum(array_3d )`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not looping over all values. You only sum one particular value as many times as you have combinations of dimensions (`5*1`, `3*4`, `5*4`). You would need nested loops (1 loop for 1 dimension, 2 loops for 2 dimensions, 3 for 3 dimensions, etc.).

What about using a recursive function to sum up one dimension at a time?

```
def array_sum(array):
    def my_sum(a):
        S = 0
        for x in a:
            S += x
        return S
    if array.ndim == 1:
        return my_sum(array)
    return my_sum(array_sum(a) for a in array)

array_sum(array_1d)
# 15

array_sum(array_2d)
# 30

array_sum(array_3d)
# 88
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply [*flatten*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) your array and then sum the resulting 1-dimensional array:

(Note that I renamed your function to `array_sum` to avoid shadowing the builtin `sum` function)

```
def array_sum(arr):
    total = 0
    for num in arr.flatten().tolist():
        total += num

    return total
```

- You could also use the builtin `sum` instead of the `for` loop to sum the array, but I suspect that defeats the purpose of the assignment
- We could iterate over `arr.flatten()`, but I convert that to a list and iterate over the list, because it's faster to iterate over a list than an array.

```
array_sum(array_1d) # 15
array_sum(array_2d) # 30
array_sum(array_3d) # 88
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that you iterate but never use `i`.

To do what you want, you can use the `sum` method  directly:

```
import numpy as np

array_1d = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array_2d = np.array([[1,3,4,5],[1,4,5,7]])
array_3d = np.array([[[1,3,4,5],[1,4,5,7]],[[6,7,8,9],[7,8,7,6]]])

for array in (array_1d, array_2d, array_3d):
    print(sum_array(array))
# >>> 15
# >>> 30
# >>> 88
```

You will only need a custom function if you are interested in supporting different axis-summation depending on the dimension of your array, like returning a number for a 1D input but return the sum column- or row-wise for a 2D/3D input.

Another thing if you need to work with the dimension of an array, use `array.ndim` instead of `len(array.shape)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out you never use `i` in your code.

If you want to do it by iterating over each value using `shape` you could use the following code:

```
def sum(array):

     sum = 0

     shape = np.shape(array)

     if len(np.shape(array)) == 3:
         for i in range(0,shape[0]):
             for j in range (0,shape[1]):
                 for k in range (0,shape[2]):
                     sum += array[i,j,k]
     elif len(np.shape(array)) == 2:
         for i in range(0,shape[0]):
             for j in range (0,shape[1]):
                sum+= array[i,j]
     elif len(np.shape(array)) == 1:
         for i in range(0,shape[0]):
             sum += array[i]
    
     return sum
```

Keep in mind that for huge array this solution will be slow.